# MVC avoiding querystring, url too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, input, query-string

i have a table with checkbox that contains a lot of contact list, the checkbox is there for them to select a specific contact to be displayed on a textbox below. my problem is that when i tried to click the add button, it throws an error that my url is too long, mainly because it appears that it is trying to parse every input via querystring.. is there another way to make this work?

View:

```
 <table id="tblcontacts>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /><span>Select All</span>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contacts.First().Selected)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contacts.First().ContactName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contacts.First().ContactNo)
                </th>

            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.contacts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
                    </td>
                    <td id="contactname">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
                    </td>
                    <td id="contactnos">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactNo)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>

  @* Populate Contacts via Jquery(Commonscript.js) during add click *@
    <input id="hfContacts" name="hfContacts" type="hidden" />
    <input id="hfContactnos" name="hfContactnos" type="hidden" />
    <div class="buttons">
        <input id="btnadd" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
$('#btnadd').click(function () {
    //get txtMessageTo value
    contactname = $('#txtMessageTo').val() || "";

    if (contactname != "")
        contactname += ',';

    //check <tr> for checked status where <td id="contact">
    $('#tblcontacts tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').children('#contactname').each(function () {
        thisContact = $(this);
        // Checks if contact was previously added already.
        if (!(contactname.indexOf($.trim(thisContact.text())) > -1))
            contactname += $.trim(thisContact.text()) + ',';
    });

    $('#hfContacts').val(contactname);
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateMessage(string hfContacts, string hfContactnos)

//adds contacts to model to be displayed on a separate textbox form
```

Comment: Can you show the `<form...>` or `@Html.BeginForm...` part of the view?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way having JavaScript populate two hidden fields and not simple submit the form via post?

Comment: @DavidG its <form action="~/Message/CreateMessage" method="get"> on top of the table

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason for the JS, check out what asp.net mvc already has built in. Your controller action method takes some type of collection as a param and you html loops through using a for (not foreach) with index values.

Check out this oldie but goodie:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: i used javascript to retain previously added contacts in the list. coz everytime I add a new contact, and the get methods fires, it erases previously added contacts on the textbox.

Comment: If I understand you want to create a message to all contacts in your list that you have selected correct? So you will want to submit to the CreateMessage action method?

Comment: yes. im creating a form that looks like, outlook. my tblcontacts is inside an accordion pane, everytime the add button is fired, get method for createmessage will fire.

Comment: Not at computer so I'll do my best. Change CreateMessage param to Contacts[] contacts. In your razor change foreach to for making sure you reference items like this contact[i].selected etc. When you form submits you'll pull out all rows in the array where selected = true. Then you can do your string building in the action method and return to have that value used in the text field. No intercepting the submit with JS.